# Two table vertically with one acting as header for another and there column and width is not align

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 table (To make make my header fixed I am using this approach). All table width is in percentage for responsive approach.

**Table 1:** Only to show header(only one column).

**Table2:** To show data.It's wrapped in div with style `height:70px & overflow:auto;` hence it it can be scrollable.

Both table have same width, but it is not aligned in line, If I remove `height:70px` then it works, it is due to scrollbar I think.

**Question:**

**1.** Is any solution to fill space(attached image)[image]

**2.** Is there any way to show scrollbar
    out of div.

[JSFIDDLE for same.](https://jsfiddle.net/Mikephils/tp0ht500/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st and 2nd points are actually related. The second table's width is being affected because it is including the width of the vertical scrollbar. Something you could try to fix *both* of your issues is to compensate for the 17px width of the scrollbar by doing this on your second DIV:

```
width: calc(90% + 17px);
```

And making your table 100% width:

```
width: 100%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tp0ht500/2/

You can use CSS `calc` to combine pixel and percentage widths, which in this case allows you to match the width while taking the width of the scrollbar into account.

Comment: Tyler Roper: It's is good solution. Is it possible to reduce gap between scrollbar and content. Table and content have too much space. +1

Comment: If data is coming less than height then again it will be mess.Any good solution??
https://jsfiddle.net/Mikephils/tp0ht500/5/

Comment: @MikePhils You could use javascript to check the table's height and apply the CSS if it's greater than 70px, or you could have the scrollbar display all the time. (It would just be disabled at heights where it isn't needed, but the width would be static)